# Not displaying day of the week using calendar and date instances

Tags: java, date, calendar, locale

I have created new SimpleDateFormat object which parses the given string as date object. The date format is as below:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpledateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

And I am setting this date to calendar instance as below:

```
Date date = sampledateFormat.parse("01-08-2013");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
```

Now I am getting the day of the day of the week from this calendar. It is giving wrong value.

```
System.out.println(calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

The output it is giving is 7 i.e. Saturday but the expected value is 5 i.e. Thursday. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should print

```
calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

The `Calendar` class has `DAY_OF_WEEK` as integer constant (with value 7) which should be used in conjunction with the `Calendar.get(int)` method. `DAY_OF_WEEK` is a calendar field, and all these constant fields are used to `get()` different values from the `calendar` instance. Their value is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse(    // Parse the input string by specified formatting pattern to get a date-only `LocalDate` object.
    "01-08-2013" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" )
)
.getDayOfWeek()    // Get a `DayOfWeek` enum object. This is *not* a mere String.
.getValue()        // Ask the `DayOfWeek` object for its number, 1-7 for Monday-Sunday per ISO 8601 standard.
```

> 4

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time*  classes that supplanted the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` and `Calendar`.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Define a formatting pattern to match.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" ) ;
```

Parse the input string.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "01-08-2013" , f ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2013-08-01

Interrogate for the day-of-week. Get a `DayOfWeek` enum object, one of seven pre-defined objects, for Monday-Sunday.

```
DayOfWeek dow = ld.getDayOfWeek() ;
```

> dow.toString(): THURSDAY

You can ask that `DayOfWeek` object for a localized name and for a number 1-7 for Monday-Sunday per the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

```
int dowNumber = dow.getValue() ;
```

> 4

```
String output = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;  // Or Locale.US, Locale.ITALY, etc.
```

> jeudi

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).